# How to avoid (xparse) environment box from breaking interline-spacing and getting inside space of preceding environment's box?

Tags: spacing, line-spacing, xparse

Interline spacing of the last line of the first environment is being infringed upon by the first line of the following environment. How do I retain proper interline spacing in such case?

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse}
\begin{document}
  \NewDocumentEnvironment{myEnv}{+b}
    { \parbox{40mm}
        { #1
        }
    } {}
  \begin{myEnv}
    This is sentence 1. This is sentence 2.
     This is sentence 3.
  \end{myEnv}\par
  % INTERLINE SPACING IS BAD HERE
  \begin{myEnv}
    This is sentence 1. This is sentence 2.
     This is sentence 3.
  \end{myEnv}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it's tricky in general (you are using vertically centred parboxes so lose all information about top and bottom baselines) it helps to put a `\strut` at the start and end of the text, but exact positioning is easier if you know you are in a context where only `myEnv` can occur. (This isn't related to xparse really, you would see the same if you just used two parboxes and no definition at all.

Comment: the other solution of course, which I didn't address in my answer is to not have the parbox, do you need a box in your real application?

Comment: huh?  the fact that is a box and the spacing settings with that are entirely unconnected, do you need it to be a box (eg to prevent page breaking or some other reason)

Comment: both  vertical spacing and parshape are set just as easily out of parbox (using identical commands) only use a box if you need a box (eg to stop page breaking or to put two side by side) positioning parboxes is quite tricky as you see here,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

As you are using vertically centred parboxes, they have large height and depth and so tex can not maintain the baseline-to-baseline space between their reference points so it stacks them vertically, separated by `\lineskip` (defaulting to 1pt) and `\parskip`.

If you add `\strut` then the boxes if stacked would have their baselines separated by `\baselineskip` however there is still the additional `\lineskip` as shown in the second example.

If you have sufficient control over the input that you know you are setting a sequence of these boxes, you can suppress the `\lineskip` with (for example) `nointerlineskip` and just rely on the `\strut` to space the lines, as shown in the final example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\showoutput
\showboxdepth=3

\begin{document}

\parbox{40mm}{This is sentence 1. This is sentence 2. This is sentence 3.}


\parbox{40mm}{This is sentence 1. This is sentence 2. This is sentence 3.}



\bigskip

\parbox{40mm}{\strut This is sentence 1. This is sentence 2. This is sentence 3.\strut }


\parbox{40mm}{\strut This is sentence 1. This is sentence 2. This is sentence 3.\strut }


\bigskip

\parbox{40mm}{\strut This is sentence 1. This is sentence 2. This is sentence 3.\strut }

\nointerlineskip
\parbox{40mm}{\strut This is sentence 1. This is sentence 2. This is sentence 3.\strut }


\end{document}
```

The terminal output for the three cases is

---

```
...\hbox(17.97223+12.97221)x345.0, glue set 216.18898fil []
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
...\glue(\lineskip) 1.0
...\hbox(17.97223+12.97221)x345.0, glue set 216.18898fil []
```

---

```
...\hbox(20.5+15.5)x345.0, glue set 216.18898fil []
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
...\glue(\lineskip) 1.0
...\hbox(20.5+15.5)x345.0, glue set 216.18898fil []
```

---

```
...\hbox(20.5+15.5)x345.0, glue set 216.18898fil []
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
...\hbox(20.5+15.5)x345.0, glue set 216.18898fil []
```

---